# Using hsc2hs with HPack and Stack

Tags: haskell, preprocessor, haskell-stack, hsc2hs, hpack

I'd like to use hsc2hs via Stack and HPack. The problem is, since HPack doesn't allow me to list the `.hsc` file as a source file, only `.hs`, changes to the `.hsc` file don't trigger a rebuild in `stack build`.

My `package.yaml` file is as follows:

```
name: bounce-bench
version: 0.1.0
category: acme

dependencies:
  - base

source-dirs:
  - src

executables:
  sim-ffi:
    source-dirs: sim
    main: sim-ffi.hs

    build-tools: hsc2hs
    c-sources:
        - csim/Bounce.h
        - csim/Bounce.c
    include-dirs: csim
```

With the above file, the initial `stack build` succeeds (incl. building `sim-ffi.hs` from `sim-ffi.hsc`), however, subsequent `stack build` invocations don't do anything if `sim-ffi.hsc` is changed.

If I try to change the `main` key's value from `sim-ffi.hs` to `sim-ffi.hsc`, I am explicitly told off:

```
Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5: The 'main-is' field must specify a
'.hs' or '.lhs' file (even if it is generated by a preprocessor), or it may
specify a C/C++/obj-C source file.
```

Comment: I am not even sure where I should list `Bounce.h`, because it is not an `hsc2hs` input; however, it is still a file that should trigger a rebuild.